# Align a image on left table?

Tags: html, css

The code below, when I view this on a  HTML editor and preview this in a web browser, both images are on the left hand side and top of one another. I want to put one image on right and one on the left with the text Help us improve how we serve the community in the center. How would I achieve this?

i.e. 
"IMAGE1" Help us improve how we serve the community "IMAGE2"

```html
<div class="survey-title">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr align="right">
        <td style="width: 40px !important;">
          <div id="uploadImage">
            <img style="display: inline;" id="imgPreview" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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"
              alt="Logo1" title="Logo1">
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>


      <tr align="right">
        <td style="width: 40px !important;">
          <div id="uploadImage">
            <span style="float:left;"></span>
            <img style="display: inline;" id="imgPreview" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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"
              alt="Logo2" title="Logo2">
            <td>

              <div type="text" id="survey-name" class="survey-name survey-headers survey-name-image" placeholder="Untitled Survey" disabled="true" title="Help us improve how we serve the best community" aria-label="Help us improve how we serve the community">Help us improve how we serve the community</div>
            </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
```

Comment: Are you using a table for a particular reason here? Are you going to display actual tabular data? Or is it just to align the items?

Comment: @IvanS95 im using a table to align items and for a particular reason, could I use tables to achieve what I asked?

Comment: You can, it would be just putting the images as first and last items inside a `tr` and the text in the middle, but I'd recommend using the table only for the data, not for presentation; you could achieve the same result using flexbox and it would be a lot easier and does not require a `table`

Comment: Unless this is an email template, then you shouldn't use tables for layout

Answer (score 0):

You have to use 3 `tds` inside a single `tr`.
Just like this example:

```html
<div class="survey-title">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div id="uploadImage">
            <img id="imgPreview" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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"
              alt="Logo1" title="Logo1">
          </div>
        </td>
    

<td>
              <div type="text" id="survey-name" class="survey-name survey-headers survey-name-image" placeholder="Untitled Survey" disabled="true" title="Help us improve how we serve the best community" aria-label="Help us improve how we serve the community">Help us improve how we serve the community</div>
            </td>
     
        <td>
          <div id="uploadImage">
            <img style="display: inline;" id="imgPreview" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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"
              alt="Logo2" title="Logo2">
            <td>

      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
```

Comment: how would I use CSS for this?

Answer (score 0):

As comments sugguest above, you shouldn't use tables for layouts unless developing an email template. However it is possible by using one table row and having the table cells in the order you require:

```html
<div class="survey-title">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr align="right">
        
        <td style="width: 40px !important;">
          <div id="uploadImage">
            <span style="float:left;"></span>
            <img style="display: inline;" id="imgPreview" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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"
              alt="Logo2" title="Logo2">
            <td>

              <div type="text" id="survey-name" class="survey-name survey-headers survey-name-image" placeholder="Untitled Survey" disabled="true" title="Help us improve how we serve the best community" aria-label="Help us improve how we serve the community">Help us improve how we serve the community</div>
            </td>
<td style="width: 40px !important;">
          <div id="uploadImage">
            <img style="display: inline;" id="imgPreview" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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"
              alt="Logo1" title="Logo1">
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using Table**

Tables are organized in rows `tr`, and inside of them we have cells `td`, for you to have the alignment you need, you only have to put the items in the right order insider a row; in this case that would be `Image1` - `Text` - `Image2`, each of these would go in a `td` element inside the same `tr` element.

Unless you are creating an email template however, I'd not recommend using tables to create a layout.

```html
<div class="survey-title">
  <table>
    <tbody>
    <!-- Single tr element -->
      <tr>
      <!-- Image1 td element -->
        <td style="width: 40px !important;">
          <div id="uploadImage">
            <img id="imgPreview" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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"
              alt="Logo1" title="Logo1">
          </div>
        </td>

        <!-- Text td element -->
        <td>
          <div type="text" id="survey-name" class="survey-name survey-headers survey-name-image" placeholder="Untitled Survey" disabled="true" title="Help us improve how we serve the best community" aria-label="Help us improve how we serve the community">Help us improve how we serve the community</div>
        </td>
        
        <!-- Image2 td element -->
        <td style="width: 40px !important;">
          <div id="uploadImage">
            <img id="imgPreview" src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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"
              alt="Logo2" title="Logo2">
          </div>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

**Using Flexbox**

I'd recommend using flexbox to align items in a single row that DO NOT require a table.

```css
.container{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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"
  />
  <div>
    Help us improve how we serve the community
  </div>
  <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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"
  />
</div>
```